# Should for loop counters be local

Tags: lua

Right now, I've been making my for loops like this

```
local i
for i = 1, 10 do
  --stuff
end
```

Since I thought you should try to keep things `local` for better performance and reduce risk from errors.

However, I've noticed that it is common to simply use.

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  --stuff
end
```

Is using `local` preferred, or is omitting it pretty harmless?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(EDIT) There's no difference between the code samples you gave. However, be aware that the variable you defined with `local i` is not the same variable that is used within your `for i = 1, 10 do` loop. When the loop exits, the original value of `i` remains unchanged (that is, `i == nil`).

siffiejoe points out that loop control/counter variables are *never* accessible outside of the loop, even if the same variable name was defined in advance. Any references to the variable *within* the loop will use the loop value. Any references *outside* of the loop will use the original, or non-loop value.

For this reason, it's safe to reuse an existing variable name in a `for` statement without corrupting the original. If you want to access the counter variable *after* the loop, you can define an extra variable beforehand and update it at within the loop as follows (siffiejoe's example):

```
local j
for i = 1, 10 do
    j = i
    --[[ stuff ]]
end
print(j) -- j stores the last value of i before the loop exits
```

Documentation: [Numeric for](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html)

Comment: Actually no. You cannot access the loop variable outside the loop body even if you declare a(nother) `local` variable with the same name outside. Loop variables are always local to the for loop body. What you **can** do is the following: `local j; for i = 1, 10 do j = i; --[[ stuff ]] end`, and access `j` after the loop.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: don't add `local i` before the `for` loop, because it's useless and confusing.

---

The `for` loop starts a new block, the control variable (`i` here) is already local to this block. Adding the `local i` is similar to:

```
local i
do
    local i = 0
    -- do something
end
```

Note that the `i` inside the block is a totally new variable, which shadows the `i` outside. When the block is over, the `i` outside the block gets its life back, but has no knowledge of what happened inside the block because the two variables have no relationship except having the same name.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop control-structure in Lua have some particularities, it's not exactly the equivalent of a C `for` loop.

One of these particularities is that its index variable is controlled by the loop. The index var is itself local and modifying it inside the loop has in fact no effect. Example:

```
for i=1,5 do
   io.write(("i: %d; "):format(i))
   i = i + 10 -- this has no effect, as 'for' is in control of the index var.
end
```

Result:

```
i: 1; i: 2; i: 3; i: 4; i: 5;
```